# MediaPlayerNative(13949): error (1, -19) - audioplayers library - Flutter

Tags: android, flutter, dart, web, audio

My app plays two audios simultaneously, with two different sources, one from **assets**, and one from **remote** .

For this, i use [audioplayers](https://pub.dev/packages/audioplayers) library to read the audio file from assets , and [flutter_audio](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_radio) to read stream from url.

everything works fine, but after a while, a got this error : and the sound from **assets** stop playing
[image]

my AndroidManifest.xml file :

[image]

This is my Code :

```
import 'dart:async';
import 'package:audioplayers/audio_cache.dart';
import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_radio/flutter_radio.dart';

class Snipet extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _SnipetState createState() => _SnipetState();
}

class _SnipetState extends State<Snipet> {
  static const streamUrl =
      "https://stream.hitradio-ohr.de/hitradio_ohr";

  bool isPlaying = false;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    audioStart();
  }

  Future<void> audioStart() async{
    await FlutterRadio.audioStart();
    print('Audio Start OK');
  }
  AudioCache player = AudioCache();

  play(){
    player.play('sound.wav');
  }



@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Center(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
          children: <Widget>[
            Column(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
              children: [
                Row(
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                  children: <Widget>[
                    FloatingActionButton(
                      child: Icon(
                       Icons.music_note,
                        color: Colors.black,
                        size: 50,
                      ),
                      elevation: 0.0,
                      backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
                      onPressed: () {
                        play();
                      },
                    )
                  ],
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),

      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        backgroundColor: Colors.green,
        child: Icon( Icons.play_arrow),
        onPressed: (){
          isPlaying != isPlaying;
          setState(() {
            FlutterRadio.playOrPause(url: streamUrl);
          });
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Screenshot

[image]

Thank you

Comment: Is it possible to add some code snippet ?

Comment: you can check now, i just add snippet of my code, thanks !